# I've tried Ubuntu for a while and want Windows back

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, disk

I have tried Ubuntu for a while, and now I want Windows back. But when I put in my USB stick that I have made bootable, it is like the computer can't find it. I just come into a menu that asks me if I want to start "Ubuntu or advanced settings" or something like that.

When I installed it I chose to make the disk full-encrypted. Do you think that is the reason the computer can't boot the USB stick?

Comment: No. Is BIOS booting from usb devices first?

Comment: @Glenn Are you talking about a USB stick for installing Windows? If so, maybe [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu) will help.

Comment: First make your USB device as primary boot device in the BIOS setting.Then boot.